# How to display horizontally report data using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I use CodeIgniter framework for developing RD Analysis report. But in that report Header and sub_headers append dynamically. And I want to get data passing date and route id. And also when I got the headers when it one subcategory change to another subcategory that between want to print total column. That part I complete but when I get qty record for display in unique sub header lines, its not displaying .Only one qty record shown.
Here I upload when I get query data.

Here that picture I get qty like this. I pass route id 
the unique code below want to display that qty.
But when I alert it get only one record.

```
   $qty="SELECT 

tphsc. `product_id`,
tphsc.`sub_category_id`,
CONCAT(sum(tsohi.qty),'-',sub_category_id) as qty, 
tp.code ,
tp.`added_date`
FROM `tbl_product_has_sub_catgory` tphsc

inner join `tbl_sales_order_has_item` tsohi
on tsohi.`product_id`= tphsc.`product_id` 

inner join `tbl_product` tp 
on tp.`product_id` = tphsc.product_id

inner join `tbl_sales_order` tso
on tso.`id_sales_order` = tsohi.`id_sales_order`    

  WHERE tso.`route_id` =$value->route_id group by tphsc.sub_category_id ";
$product_qty= $this->db->mod_select($qty);
```

I pass that query data using sub array.

```
   'qty'=>$product_qty->qty
```

My report view like,

> ![Here using that picture I think can get what kind of report it.][2]
>
> [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlUOb.png

In javascript I pass data,

```
  +'<td style="text-align:right">' + order['rd'][x].qty + '</td>'
```

How I display it unique code below and how to display horizontally.

ajax

```
   $j.ajax({
    url: 'drow_sales_order',
    method: 'post',
    data: {

        txt_sales_order_id: $j('#txt_sales_order_id').val(),
        txt_sales_ref_id: $j('#txt_sales_ref_id').val(),
        txt_id_store: $j("select[name='cmb_outlet'] option:selected").val(),
        cmb_teritory: $j("select[name='cmb_teritory'] option:selected").val(),
        cmb_culster: $j("select[name='cmb_culster'] option:selected").val(),
        cmb_area: $j("select[name='cmb_area'] option:selected").val(),
        cmb_region: $j("select[name='cmb_region'] option:selected").val(),
        txt_start_date: $j('#txt_start_date').val(),
        ref_id: $j("select[name='cmb_rep'] option:selected").val(),
        cmb_agency: $j("select[name='cmb_agency'] option:selected").val(),
        cmb_rep_area: $j("select[name='cmb_rep_area'] option:selected").val(),
        cmb_route: $j("select[name='cmb_route'] option:selected").val(),
        txt_end_date: $j('#txt_end_date').val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var order = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(data);
        var order_detail = [];
        var order_qty = [];


        for (var x = 0; x < order['rd'].length; x++) {

//                for (var i = 0; i <order['rd'][i].qty.length; i++) {
//                    order_qty.push(
//                            '<td style="text-align:right">' + order['rd']  [x].qty[i] + '</td>'
//                            );
//                    
 //                }
            // alert(order['rd'][x].qty);
            order_detail.push(
                    '<tr>'
                    + '<td style="text-align:center">' + order['rd'][x].date + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="text-align:left">' + order['rd'][x].ter_name + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="text-align:right">' + order['rd'][x].sales_total + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="text-align:right">' + order['rd'][x].discount + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="text-align:right">' + order['rd'][x].persantage + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="text-align:right">' + order['rd'][x].tot + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="text-align:right">' + order['rd'][x].return_amount + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="text-align:right">' + order['rd'][x].total + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="text-align:right"></td>'
                    + '<td style="text-align:right">' + order['rd'][x].retailer_count + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="text-align:right">' + order['rd'][x].calls_mate + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="text-align:right">' + order['rd'][x].productive + '</td>'
                    + '<td style="text-align:right"></td>'
                    + '<td style="text-align:right"></td>'
                    + '<td style="text-align:right">' + order['rd'][x].gross_after + '</td>'
                    +'<td style="text-align:right">' + order['rd'][x].qty + '</td>'
                    );
```

controller

```
    public function drow_sales_order() {
      echo json_encode($this->rd_analysis_model->get_rd_analysis());
   //        $routedata = $this->rd_analysis_model->get_rd_analysis();
   //        $routecount = count($routedata);
   //
   //        for ($i = 0; $i < $routecount; $i++) {
  //            $routedata[$i]->rqty = $this->rd_analysis_model-  >routeqty($routedata[$i]->route_id);
     //        }
     //
     //        echo json_encode($routecount);
        }
```

Comment: Is it necessary to display data using javascript? You can use view and assign it to the div though. What would you like?

Comment: call ajax and return view from controller. And assign it to table or div.
$data['view'] = $this->load->view('create_table',$data,true);
echo json_encode($data);

Comment: normally i used javascript and ajax.in view i used table. the problem i want to get headers dynamically.and how to display qty in unique code belows

Comment: wait i'll upload that report ajax and controller

Comment: @amaya why you are not returning all view in ajax and just append or assign where you want it ? just mention above in comments

Comment: $j('#rd_body').html(order_detail);.. like this i append data. i want to append qty data horizontally that correct code blowe